# addPlugin function issues in typo3 6.2.14

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I did an upgrade from typo3 4.5.0 to 6.2.14 and I get an issue with a custom extension which one of its functionality is to include custom plugins that are stored in extensions directory.

The plugins that are going to be included used the code below. The location of this code is in extensionkey/ext_tables.php

```
if (file_exists($path) && is_dir($path)) {      
        $files = scandir($path);    
        foreach ($files as $f) {
            if (is_dir($path.$f) && $f!='.' && $f!='..' && $f!='.svn') {            
                $TCA['tt_content']['types']['list']['subtypes_excludelist'][$_EXTKEY.'_'.$f]='layout,select_key,pages';
                $confArr = array('LLL:EXT:extensionkey/locallang_db.xml:tt_content.list_type_'.$f, $_EXTKEY.'_'.$f, '');
                t3lib_extMgm::addPlugin($confArr,'list_type');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just a shot into the blue: Don't use `$TCA`, replace it with `$GLOBALS['TCA']`. Does that help?

Comment: Also, what does go wrong? Are the plugins not appearing in the list?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes are not appearing in the plugin list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable the "Development Mode" in the install tool, then you will see all errors. `t3lib_extMgm::addPlugin` does not exist in TYPO3 6.2 anymore and should result in an exception. It must be replaced with `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility`

Comment: Thanks. I have decided to add for each file